# understanding DAG: node creation

Tags: llvm

I have an intrinsic and it must be lowered to instruction, which works with fixed register.
So, it takes contents of this register and another argument as input.  After execution, the result of the instruction is placed into that same fixed register.

What should I do in `SelectionDAGBuilder::visitIntrinicCall` to describe such behaviour for a SDNode?